# Excel copy cell values to other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a macro to copy certain rows (if column A isn't blank) of worksheet 'A' to worksheet 'B'. After a little bit of research the following code suddenly appeared. Only thing that I don't seem to work out is to copy the cell values instead of the linked formula, I tried to implement the 'copy/paste special' command, but I don't get the specific coherent code language.

```
Sub Samenvattend()
'
' Samenvattend Macro
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+Shift+S
'

Dim a As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("gedetailleerde meetstaat")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("samenvattende meetstaat")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each a In Source.Range("A1:A10000")   ' Do 10000 rows
    If a <> "" Then
       Source.Rows(a.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)

       j = j + 1
    End If
Next a
End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What if you do `Target.Rows(j).Value = Source.Rows(a.Row).Value`?

Comment: Aight, that solves my problem, thanks!

Comment: @BruceWayne this would be a good reference for others in the future, would you mind making it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to set the values of two cells equal, you can skip copy/paste, and simply set the ranges' values equal to one another.

This also lets you skip using the Clipboard and tends to be a little faster.

Just remember when doing this, it's `[DESTINATION range].value = [ORIGIN range].value` whereas with `copy/paste`, it's `[ORIGIN range].copy [DESTINATION range]`.

```
For Each a In Source.Range("A1:A10000")   ' Do 10000 rows
    If a <> "" Then
       Target.Rows(j).value = Source.Rows(a.Row).Value
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next a
```